# Calculating optimal bins in histogram in terms of date

Tags: algorithm, histogram, binning

I've a search API that allows me to extract the data on the basis of query which also include date queries, such as

`query : 'ids created between date 11/04/2017 to 20/03/2019'`

now if I want to cluster these ids and create bins. What is the best algorithm to obtain whether I should bin by week, month, year, etc.
basically, I want an optimal algorithm to create bins and bin-width.

Comment: It depends on your application. What do you wanna do after packing these dates? What types of query you will have over these dates?

Comment: I want to cluster it up on the basis of count of ids made in a week , month and so on . but i want an optimal way to obtain the bins such as they have even distribution all across the board.